# Why doesn't this simple AJAX PHP form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

World's simplest PHP form isn't submitting. I simply want a form to be submitted whenever a user clicks on an image. At present absolutely nothing happens. Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
<script>
function changeImage(id) {
document.images[id].src = "x";
var datastring = 'orderID=13&partID=' + id;
submit; 

$.ajax
(
  {

    type: "POST",
    url: "allocatepartssubmit.php",
    data: dataString ,
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('failure');
    }
  });

}

</script>
```

The relevant html line:

```
<img src="x" onclick="changeImage('x')" id="x">
```

I have replaced various parts with an 'x' for ease of viewing. The js image switch works fine so I know the changeimage() function is being called. But the form isnt posting. It doesn't alert either success or failure, implying the contents of .ajax aren't being seen.

Wat do?

Comment: `submit;` doesn't call anything... BTW, which FORM are you talking about???

Comment: if u want to submit the form use this `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`

Comment: Apologies guys but I've figured out the problem!! It was that I had datastring and dataString. That's it! And yes, the 'submit' line was from a previous bit of code, it's now redundant. Sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, sweet & short code for you!!

```
<img src="exapmle.png" class="change_image" id="x">
```

**jquery -**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.change_image').live('click',function(){

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var dataStr = 'orderID=13&partID=' + id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "allocatepartssubmit.php",
            data: dataString ,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
              alert('success');
            },
            error: function(err){
              alert('failure');
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
<script>
function changeImage(id) {
var datastring = 'orderID=13&partID=' + id;

$.ajax
(
  {

    type: "POST",
    url: "allocatepartssubmit.php",
    data: dataString ,
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('failure');
    }
  });

}

</script>
```

Remove `submit;` and `document.images[id].src = "x";` from your code as these are not in use.